# Django: how to update multiple records?

Tags: python, django

I need to update multiple records (rows) in a table.

First, I get informations to select rows to be update:

```
ran_st1 = 1
ran_st2 = 1
ran_bra = 'A'
pay_ide = 'FR'
bra_lib = 'Polyvitamines et oligo-éléments'
```

Then, I select rows to be updated:

```
rows= Randomisation.objects.filter(Q(ran_st1 = ran_st1) & Q(ran_st2 = ran_st2) & Q(ran_bra = ran_bra) & Q(pay_ide = pay_ide))
```

And then, I though to make a loop like that, but not sure:

```
for row in rows:
    r = get_object_or_404(Randomisation, ran_ide = row.ran_ide)
    r.ran_act = 1
    r.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update with [**`.update(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
Randomisation.objects.filter(
    ran_st1=ran_st1,
    ran_st2 = ran_st2,
    ran_bra = ran_bra,
    pay_ide = pay_ide
).update(ran_act=1)
```

This will work with a query that looks like:

```
UPDATE randomisation
SET ran_act = 1
WHERE ran_st1 = 1
  AND ran_st2 = 1
  AND ran_bra = 'A'
  AND pay_ide = 'FR'
  AND bra_lib = 'Polyvitamines et oligo-elements'
```

This is thus done in *one* query, not in several queries where you each time fetch an element, update that element, and then make an update query to the database for that specific record.